# Unable to access a post's insights for someone else's page

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

When I access this resource:

https://graph.facebook.com/xxx_yyy/insights

I get this response:

```
{
  "data": [
  ], 
  "paging": {
    "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx_yyy/insights?format=json&since=-86400&until=0", 
    "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/xxx_yyy/insights?format=json&since=0&until=86400"
  }
}
```

The insights data is empty.  "xxx_yyy" is a valid post id I got from the feed.

- I have the read_insights permission.
- I have the offline_access permission.
- I'm an admin on the page.
- The page has more than 30 likes.

What's causing the API to return an empty insights array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few requirements for you to get data back from the Facebook Insights graph API call. These don't appear to be clearly documented anywhere, but this is what I have found by trial and error.

- The post must be from the page itself, posts from other people won't return insights data

  - Look at the id in the From object within the post response from facebook, if that is different than the page_id, you won't get metrics.
  - It's good to note that I haven't unequivocally proved this point, just some anecdotal testing seems to point in this direction
- The post must be quite old, I was able to dig up something on one of their Ads FAQs that post insights won't be available for 12-15 hours after the end of the day they were posted on.

  > "Page post metrics will be available 12 to 15 hours after the end of the day the post was made. Metrics are logged on Pacific Standard Time." [Page Post Metrics FAQ -Ads and Business Solutions](http://www.facebook.com/help/?page=258216927554796)

  - I have yet to determine the exact age that posts need to be precisely, but my guess is 36 hours would be a safe general bet. That being said, Facebook Insights data has been known to fall behind from time to time, so I would assume that the timing with which you can attain data will be variable.

FB documentation on page post insights is available primarily in this [Facebook blog post](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/573/)

Comment: Nice answer, learning new stuff!  Thanks for the "insights" into insight stats.

Comment: I should note that FB is now saying that marketers will get access to insights in realtime. I don't know if or when this will extend to the insights graph table. I'll try to remember to update this post if I learn more.

Answer (score 2):

Invalid ID is a key. xxx_yyy in the question means ID must be a combination of appID (xxx part) and postID (yyy part).

So, here is the right Url for post-related metrics:

[https://graph.facebook.com/[appID]_[postID]/insights](https://graph.facebook.com/appID_postID/insights)

Comment: This is half correct. For page posts XXX is the page id, not app id. This is what worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You must use PAGE token not USER token.

1. connect to app with manage_pages and read_insights permission
2. run api https://graph.facebook.com/me/accounts?access_token=USERTOKEN
   this expression lists all pages with access token for each page, that you save and use the expression for the post insights

then run expr.
https://graph.facebook.com/xxx_yyy/insights?access_token=PAGETOKEN