# Reading facebook post using graph API which app posted

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql, facebook-insights

My application is posting on wall on behalf of the user with user access_token. Once it is posted I get back the post_id which is persisted in DB. An an application I would like to query the post using the post_id to collect some basic insights like comments and likes. I can't get my app to query the data.

I tried stream table but doesn't return data as an app. I get "GraphMethodException" code:100
I checked privacy settings on post but that doesn't include permission for an app
I tried GraphAPI /post_id which returns same error as stream table
I tried insights table with post_impressions metric with no luck. I couldn't give the post_id so tried removing the user_id part from post_id(xxxx_yyyy where xxxx is the userid)

What kind of permissions do I need to request user to grant my application stream_read permission?

How do I query insights table with the post_id that I have?

Comment: Error no. 100 corresponds to `Invalid Parameter` Refer : http://www.fb-developers.info/tech/fb_dev/faq/general/gen_10.html Show us your code so we get an idea. This should be helpful : https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/ You can get the comments and likes, and do a count as well(If you are looking for the count).

Comment: There isn't really any code. I am using graphAPI explorer or fql console to query insights.

Comment: What are you typing into the Graph API explorer? o_O

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only read the user wall with an active user access token, and the read_stream permission.

About the insights: maybe with this graph connection?

```
/[post-id]/insights
```

Well, it gives me nothing for a valid post id. But i am sure you can only get the insights of pages, not user accounts.
See here (about pages, but maybe useful additional info): [Unable to access a post's insights for someone else's page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489651/unable-to-access-a-posts-insights-for-someone-elses-page)

One more reason why it will not work, just popped up in my head:
If you go to a facebook page, you have the insights view as admin. Nothing like that on a user profile. So the only thing you can track is how often a link to your app has been clicked after posting it to a user profile. You can easily add tracking information to the link too, so you always know from which profile the click comes.

Comment: I confirm that /[page-id]/insights work for pages ONLY and not for posts. How does this work? https://www.facebook.com/help/193570080689486/

I tried getting read_stream extended permission from user but it doesn't help.

Comment: i am 99% sure that there just are no insights for user profiles

Comment: I am starting to believe that there isn't one. It was a misconception on my part that I could get metrics for the wall posts.

Comment: please don´t forget to accept my answer if it helped you, even if the answer is that it just doesn´t work (what´s pretty clear now, i guess) :)